# "Why isn't my Discord bot sending messages to new members when they join the server?"

Tags: javascript, node.js, web, discord, discord.js

The bot should bring the newcomer into the 'verificaton' channel and ask them questions to verify the user but when they join they see Rules Screening page and have to agree to rules to proceed. And that's i think might be the issue because the bot tries the access the user to bring them into the 'vefification' channel. How can I solve that issue so the bot would wait until the user agrees to all rules and does all the 'Welcome Page' stuff to finally bring them into the necessary channel and ask them necessary questions?

**My bot's code:**

```js
const fs = require('fs');
const { Client, GatewayIntentBits } = require('discord.js');
const config = require('./config.json');

const client = new Client({ 
    intents: [GatewayIntentBits.Guilds, GatewayIntentBits.GuildMessages, GatewayIntentBits.GuildMembers, GatewayIntentBits.MessageContent] 
});

// Replace this with your questions and answers
const questions = [
    { question: 'What is the capital of France?', answers: ['Paris', 'London', 'Berlin'] },
    { question: 'What is the largest mammal?', answers: ['Blue Whale', 'Elephant', 'Giraffe'] },
    { question: 'What is the smallest planet in our solar system?', answers: ['Mercury', 'Mars', 'Pluto'] },
];

function randomizeQuestions() {
    const randomizedQuestions = [];

    // Fisher-Yates shuffle algorithm
    for (let i = questions.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
        const j = Math.floor(Math.random() * (i + 1));
        [questions[i], questions[j]] = [questions[j], questions[i]];
    }

    for (const question of questions) {
        randomizedQuestions.push({ ...question });
    }

    return randomizedQuestions;
}

client.once('ready', () => {
    console.log('Bot is ON!');
});

client.on('guildMemberAdd', async member => {
    const unverifiedRole = member.guild.roles.cache.get('************');
    member.roles.add(unverifiedRole);

    const verificationChannel = member.guild.channels.cache.find(channel => channel.name === 'verification');

    if (!verificationChannel) {
        console.error('Verification channel not found');
        return;
    }

    try {
        await verificationChannel.send(`${member.user.username}, welcome to the server! Please answer the following questions in this channel to verify yourself:`);

        const randomizedQuestions = randomizeQuestions();

        for (let questionObj of randomizedQuestions) {
            const question = questionObj.question;
            const answers = questionObj.answers;
            const correctAnswer = answers[0];

            const answerList = answers.map((answer, index) => `${index + 1}. ${answer}`).join('\n');
            
            await verificationChannel.send(`**${question}**\n\n${answerList}`);
            const filter = m => m.author.id === member.user.id && !isNaN(m.content) && m.content >= 1 && m.content <= answers.length;
            const collected = await verificationChannel.awaitMessages({ filter, max: 1, time: 30000, errors: ['time'] });

            if (collected.first().content !== '1') {
                await verificationChannel.send(`${member.user.username}, sorry, your answer is incorrect. You have been removed from the server.`);
                return member.kick('Failed verification');
            }
        }
        await member.roles.add('***********');
        await verificationChannel.send(`${member.user.username}, congratulations, you have successfully verified your account! Welcome to the server.`);
    } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
    }
});

client.login(***********);
```

Comment: I believe with the "Onboarding" feature you can deter bots in a similar fashion quite easily. If you still want to use this verification process, you could have the unverified role assigned once they complete a minimalistic onboarding process (basic questions answers wouldn't matter) and then prompt them with the question.